# VBA make named range arguments to a custom function refer to both a single cell and a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

The percentrank function can take the same named range for both of its agruments like:

```
=percentrank(inputrange,inputrange)
```

It treats the first argument as a range of cells for calculating percent cutoffs, and uses the second argument to return a single cell's value to rank amongst the cutoffs.  The single cell is determined by the row in which the function is entered/called from.

I want to recreate this functionality and use the second range reference to find a single cells value (based on the row the function is entered into).  Here's what I have:

```
Public Function QUARTILE_RANK(DataRange As Range, RefCell As Range)

If RefCell <> vbNullString Then

    q1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Quartile(DataRange, 1)
    q2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Quartile(DataRange, 2)
    q3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Quartile(DataRange, 3)
    q4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Quartile(DataRange, 4)

    If (RefCell <= q1) Then QUARTILE_RANK = 1
    If (RefCell > q1) And (RefCell <= q2) Then QUARTILE_RANK = 2
    If (RefCell > q2) And (RefCell <= q3) Then QUARTILE_RANK = 3
    If (RefCell > q3) Then QUARTILE_RANK = 4
Else
    QUARTILE_RANK = vbNullString
End If

End Function
```

If I pass it the same named range for both arguments, it sees both ranges as arrays of cells.  I want it to treat the first argument that way, but find a single cell value using the second argument.  That is, I want it to mirror the functionality of the PERCENTRANK function.

EDIT:

Sean Chesire's input helped me get it working.  I'd welcome any suggestions for improvement as I'm sure this same function has been written by others.

Here's the final form:

```
Public Function QUARTILE_RANK(DataRange As Range, RefRange As Range)

Dim refCell As Range

If RefRange.Rows.Count > 1 Then
    Set refCell = RefRange.Cells(Application.Caller.Row, 1)
Else
    Set refCell = RefRange ' maybe they only passed a cell reference
End If

If refCell <> vbNullString Then

    q1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Quartile(DataRange, 1)
    q2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Quartile(DataRange, 2)
    q3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Quartile(DataRange, 3)
    q4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Quartile(DataRange, 4)

    If (refCell <= q1) Then QUARTILE_RANK = 1
    If (refCell > q1) And (refCell <= q2) Then QUARTILE_RANK = 2
    If (refCell > q2) And (refCell <= q3) Then QUARTILE_RANK = 3
    If (refCell > q3) Then QUARTILE_RANK = 4
Else
    QUARTILE_RANK = vbNullString
End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will tell you which cell the formula was called from:

```
Function testit() As String
testit = Application.Caller.Parent.Parent.Name & " " & Application.Caller.Parent.Name & " " & Application.Caller.Address
End Function
```

You should then be able to test the ranges given, and work out which value should be referenced in the other array

Comment: Thanks!  That got me where I needed to go.

Comment: Hi Casper.  If this solved your problem, then marked it as the solution (Check mark at the left of this post)

Answer (score 0):

`=LOOKUP(PERCENTRANK(vals,vals),{0,0.25,0.5,0.75},{1,2,3,4})`

Comment: This is a cleaner solution in my case, but Sean's answer is more applicable to my original question in general.  I'd tried something along these lines with "=match(quartile(" but couldn't get it to work right.  This does exactly what I need without requiring more vba code.